# не работает команда virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

в консоли пишу virtualenv --version. 
выдает:

```
"virtualenv" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

перед этим установил virtualenv, командой

```
pip install -U pip virtualenv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Папка с модулями `Python` не находится в `PATH`.

***Попробуйте:***

```py
python -m virtualenv имя_папки
```